# Quotation with double quote and O results in Ö

Tags: punctuation, quoting

I have an issue with the double quote in my quotation.

Using `"OpenGL....."` results in `ÖpenGL...` even with `\"OpenGL...` the result is the same.

Using \verb results in double quotes in a wrong font type (at least it looks out of place).

```
\begin{quotation}
"OpenGL (Open Graphics Library) ist eine Spezifikation für eine plattform-
und programmiersprachenunabhängige Programmierschnittstelle zur
Entwicklung von 2D- und 3D-Computergrafik."
\end{quotation}
```

Comment: `\shorthandoff{"}` could help, see the `babel` documentation for this command. Though it's recommendable to quote in another way, as the answers show.

Comment: Just a comment: usually in TeX, putting a backslash makes things "worse" and not "better", in that it does not escape characters to become less special, but more.  It's not like \" in, say, Linux filenames, which is a literal quotation character rather than a string delimiter.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do not use `"` for quoting, use ``` `` ``` and `''` (English quotes) or `` "` ``
and `"'` (German quotes, needs `babel`, see below) instead:

```
\begin{quotation}
"`OpenGL (Open Graphics Library) ist eine Spezifikation für eine plattform-
und programmiersprachenunabhängige Programmierschnittstelle zur
Entwicklung von 2D- und 3D-Computergrafik."'
\end{quotation}
```

The `babel` package with the `german`/`ngerman` option does the `"O` -> `Ö` translation. This is to for (old) systems which do not have the Umlauts.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I am using `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`, hope that is correct?!

Comment: This, or skip that and take a look at the `csquotes` package. (Background for the OP: "+character is special when support for german is loaded, so that "a yields ä etc. If you don't like csquotes, "` and "' will yield proper quotes.)

Comment: @Warren: This is correct (for the new orthography). It just changed the meaning of `"`.

Comment: @Ulrich: Yes, I should have mentioned `csquotes`, but I tried not to give too much information.

Answer (score 11):

The `csquotes` package has been mentioned several times, so I decided to make a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\SetBlockEnvironment{quotation}

\begin{document}

\begin{displayquote}
  \enquote{%
    OpenGL (Open Graphics Library) ist eine Spezifikation für eine plattform- und
    programmiersprachenunabhängige Programmierschnittstelle zur Entwicklung von
    2D- und 3D-Computergrafik.%
  }%
\end{displayquote}

\end{document}
```

Note that display quotes are usually set without quotation marks.

Comment: And now my beginner question: why using the % behind the  curly brackets and the text?

Comment: @Warren: a linebreak counts as a space (unless "hidden" in a oomment), and here this would result in a space, for example, after the opening quote before the word OpenGL.

Comment: @Ulrich: thanks, I just tested it and I saw the spaces... didn't know that.