# Problem with using quotations in German document

Tags: punctuation, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quotation with double quote and O results in Ö](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10867/quotation-with-double-quote-and-o-results-in)

I want to write a document in German. For it I write in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

However, if I want to use quotation marks, it messes with the results, i.e. `"E` becomes `Ë` (E with two dots above it), while all I want is to start a quotation with the letter E...

What can be done?

Comment: `"` should not be used to produce quotes.

Answer (score 15):

German quotes are done with "` and "'.

Instead the you may use the macros `\glqq` (German left double-quote) and `\grqq` (German right double-quote):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\begin{document}

Ein Kommentar: "`Zitat"'

Ein Kommentar: \glqq Zitat\grqq
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:[image: Example German quotes]

With " alone, you get Umlauts (it was (and is) used if you have problems to use 'real' Umlauts (e.g. English keyboard layout)).

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that. It's silly that they don't let me decide my use for "...

Comment: @Mike: They do let you decide your use for `"`: You can say `\shorthandoff{"}` as suggested in the link Werner posted in the comment (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10867/quotation-with-double-quote-and-o-results-in). Then `"` will produce what you typed, commas at the top of the line. However, you'll realise that this is not what you actually want.

Comment: @Mike: If you actually want to type in quotation marks, you could use the [Neo keyboard layout](http://neo-layout.org/), which offers `„` and `“` on its second layer and you XeTeX for compiling as it allows for Unicode characters. As Jake said, `"` isn't a quotation mark, technically.