# Replace "quotes" with „quotes“?

Tags: punctuation, csquotes

I live in a funny part of the world where we're required to quote text like this: `„quotes“` (note the difference between the opening and closing quote).

Is there an easy way to set up a LaTeX document so that I could just type the usual double quotes that are on my keyboard (`"like this"`), and the LaTeX document processor would replace them to the ones that I need (`„like this“`)?

I know I could just use `,,` (two commas) and ``` `` ``` (two grave accents) in the LaTeX source file, but this seems like a step-back from what Microsoft Word has to offer at this point ;-)

If LaTeX (or XeTeX, or whatever) can't do that by itself, is there a way to preprocess the LaTeX document with some sort of an regular expression (somehow embed the regexp in the document)?

**EDIT:**

The language in question is Lithuanian.

*babel* doesn't do what I want; I don't know if it's supposed to.

What I would like to achieve is the automatic `""` => `„“` replacement. Quoting text with anything more than a single keystroke doesn't seem efficient to me ;-)

Comment: Why don't you use the `csquotes` package?

Comment: Just out of curiosity what language is that?

Comment: @Linas Did you try babel with Lithuanian?

Comment: @Thorsten, could you give an example of how this would work with `csquotes`?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, I did, but the quotes don't get replaced (not sure if they're supposed to).

Comment: @Canageek German is a candidate. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10867/quotation-with-double-quote-and-o-results-in

Comment: @Linas `\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\enquote{Test}
\end{document}`

Comment: For single occurrence also `\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\begin{document} 
Text \quotedblbase text\textquotedblright{} text. 
\end{document}` might be noted.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer ("Solution") into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Using the [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package allows logical mark up of quotes. That includes 'short' quotes, which I personally would avoid but was asked for so ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\begin{document}
\enquote{Labas rytas}

"Labas rytas"
\end{document}
```

(Lithuanian `babel` doesn't seem to work 'out of the box', so I've used German as the standard quotation style is the same.)

Comment: But if the wanted language is Lithuanian, doesn't the  `\usepackage[german]{babel}` load the German hyphenation patterns?

Comment: @morbusg Yes, this was just so that the demo worked. I'm assuming that someone writing in Lithuanian will have a working `babel` set up for that language, and can therefore make the necessary adjustments to the above. (As it stands, the question does not only apply to Lithuanian, so I hope this is reasonable. After all, you could ask the same thing for German!)

Comment: I ended up doing this: `\usepackage[lithuanian,german]{babel} \usepackage{csquotes} \MakeOuterQuote{"} \selectlanguage{lithuanian}`

Answer (score 6):

For Czech, I get better results when using german quotations, as both German and Czech quote using <sub>99</sub>text<sup>66</sup>, whereas croatian uses <sub>99</sub>text<sup>99</sup>. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark, the Lithuanian style should be the same as the Czech one, so I assume german would be a better option than croatian for Lithuanian as well.

The code I use to get Czech quotes is the following:

```
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteAlias{german}{czech}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
```

I assume this should be the correct way for Lithuanian as well, just swap czech with lithuanian in the code. I see no need to load german into babel or to use selectlanguage.

Comment: FYI, I am talking about Czech in the answer, because I came here from a question specifically asking for Czech quotations (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109168/override-quotation-style?newreg=cde31d05f2884c94944b385366b260a0), which was marked as duplicate of this one, although it had been answered only partially. I have not found the proper way to handle Czech quotes using csquotes online and had to do my own research for that. However, I cannot add my findings as an answer to the original and more appropriate question as it had been closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

If you're in Windows, TeXnicCenter can also do it for you... (replacing `"` with the correct replacement as you type).