# Override quotation style

Tags: macros, punctuation

Is it possible to override the default quotation marks of ``` ``notation'' ```?

As a czech user, I have to use `\uv{}` to have czech styled quotations, which doesn't write so well.

Answer (score 2):

The package [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) is specialized in context sensitive quoting. It provides the command `\enquote{}` that enclose its argument in quotation marks. The style of the quotation marks is defined by [`babel`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel).

So you have to add

```
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
```

to your preamble and substitute the quoting by `\enquote{}`.

The results should be suitable.