# Closing quotes collapse leads to unbalanced quotes in some Balto-Slavic languages

Tags: punctuation, csquotes

The `csquotes` package does a very good job automatically placing quotation marks instead of dumb quotes in the input. This works well in many languages (e.g. [English](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531/13523), or [Lithuanian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38985/13523) ), however there is a case that it does not currently handle. That is the case when to closing quotes fall together. In Balto-Slavic languages, such as Latvian, Russian, or Belarusian this leads to unbalanced quotes, e.g.

```
  работа В.И. Ленина «О карикатуре на марксизм 
  и об «империалистическом экономизме»
```

That is

```
  The paper by V.I. Lenin «A caricature of Marxism 
  and «Imperialist Economism»
```

Note two opening quotes and only one closing quote.

Here

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
...
работа В.И. Ленина "О карикатуре на марксизм 
и об "империалистическом экономизме"
```

would cause

```
! Package csquotes Error: Unbalanced groups or invalid nesting.
```

I have come up with a small hack that seems to place the quotes correctly in my documents, however it would be nice to have a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what works for me. It is based on the following observation:

> Closing quotes are the ones followed by a space or a punctuation mark, and all other quotes are opening quotes

This rule can be implemented using `\new@ifnextchar` command from `amsgen.sty` that does not ignore spaces:

```
\usepackage{amsgen}
\makeatletter
\def\smartquote{\new@ifnextchar\@sptoken{\rightquote}{%
   \@ifnextchar.{\rightquote}{%
     \@ifnextchar,{\rightquote}{%
        \@ifnextchar){\rightquote}{\leftquote}}}}}
\def\leftquote{<<}
\def\rightquote{>>}
\makeatother
```

To bind this `\smartquote` to the double quote character one could use a method making double quote active:

```
\newcommand{\setupsmartquotes}{%
  \catcode`\"=\active %
  \begingroup
  \lccode`\~=`\"
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \def~{\smartquote}}}
```

Now to override `babel` definitions `\setupsmartquotes` can be used in `\AtBeginDocument` and after `\selectlanguage` for languages that make double quotes active.

```
\AtBeginDocument{\setupsmartquotes}
```

This would produce the expected result:

[image: Expected result]