# Quotation mark problem

Tags: punctuation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quotation with double quote and O results in Ö](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10867/quotation-with-double-quote-and-o-results-in)

I'm having a problem to write this in LaTeX: "real-world" objects. My code is this

```
``real$-$world" objects
```

But this gives me "realwordöbjects" ... I tried `\glqq` and `\grqq` but that's not really what I want. `\"` didn't work either.

Comment: ` ``real$-$world" objects ` works for me. So does  ` ``real{$-$}world" objects` . Please provide a MWE (minimal working example) showing your problem.

Comment: Why do you use a minus `$-$`, instead of a hyphen `-`? It is “real-world” rather than “real−world”.

Comment: I used - at first but it didn't seem to work for a strange reason, it works now lol..

Comment: Do you know package `csquotes`? Try `texdoc csquotes` to learn more about it ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use two `'` signs instead of one `"` sign. The latter is an active character in many `babel` languages, and `"o` produces `ö`. (Also, instead of switching to math mode to produce a minus sign, simply use a hyphen.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english,dutch]{babel}

\begin{document}

``real-world" objects

``real-world'' objects

\end{document}
```

[image]