# How to make a quotation mark "....." in LaTeX?

Tags: quotation

I want to know how to typeset quotation marks in LaTeX.

When I use quotation marks (`""`), a problem occurs: the spacing between the quoted- and unquoted-word disappears. E.g., my text looks like example (1) below. I want it to look like example (2) (notice the inter-word spacing).

(1) The mode is called "BASDF"because

(2) The mode is called "BASDF" because

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It might be a better idea to use the `csquotes` package and its `\enquote` macro. Then you don't need special chars and the actual symbol combo can be controlled from the preamble

Comment: This has nothing to do with `biblatex`, so I'll remove the tag. But let me just echo daleif's advice: Use `csquotes` to typeset quotation marks. If you use `\enquote` you don't have to worry about the exact commands/characters to typeset the typographically correct quotation marks in your language, you'll get the right output automatically. Plus you can easily switch between different styles if your language has different conventions.

Comment: You could use my `semantic-markup` package and then just write `\quoted{BASDF}`. (It uses `csquotes` under the hood)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to use quotation mark glyphs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-quotation-mark-glyphs)

Comment: -- also [punctuation - Quotation with double quote and O results in Ö - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10867/quotation-with-double-quote-and-o-results-in-%C3%96)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The mode is called ``BASDF'' because
\end{document}
```

[image: Text]

Comment: You could create a Minimal Working Example, by moving `\end{document}` up your code and continuously checking if the problem is there. -eliminate EVERYTHING until you only have the problematic code. You might find that a package or combinations of packages is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also type in curly quotes on the keyboard, in your UTF-8 source file.  A modern TeX distribution will understand them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The mode is called “BASDF” because
\end{document}
```

On older installations, you might also need to load `inputenc` or `selinput`, but UTF-8 has been the default encoding for LaTeX, in all engines, since 2018.

Comment: It would be better to specify that for modern TeX distribution you mean, if compiled with LuaLaTeX  or XeLaTeX. Otherwise, one has to include `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: @Guido That hasn’t been the case since April 2018. That line is no longer needed, in any engine.